# Magento send Order update mails

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, email-templates

I am using Marketplace in my website. In here seller can able to Process the order. I given below the code

```
public function shipementorderAction(){
                $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

                $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id);
                $order->setData('state', 'shipement');
                $order->setStatus('shipement');
                $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('', false);
                $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
                $order->save(); 

                $order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);

                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                    $this->__('The order state has been changed.')
                );

                Mage::getSingleton('core/session') ->addSuccess('Order Updated Successfully'); $this->_redirectReferer();


                }
```

I used this code to send a email to customer

```
$order->sendOrderUpdateEmail(true, null);
```

How to send copy of email to that current **seller**? **Like customer got a order status mail as well as seller also got copy of same mail**

Comment: you want to sent a custom email or use the order status email?

Comment: Custom email to seller

Answer (score 1):

add this code in marketplace module `etc/config.xml` inside the global tag

```
<template>
            <email>
              <sales_email_order_custom_comment_template translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>Order Update</label>
                    <file>sales/custom_order_update.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sales_email_order_custom_comment_template>
           </email>
  </template>
```

make copy of `order_update.html` and rename to  `custom_order_update.html`

for sending the email  add this code

```
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                    ->loadDefault('sales_email_order_custom_comment_template');
                    $emailTemplate
                    ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store->getId()));                                                  
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
                    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
                    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Order Updated Order #'.$order->getIncrementId()); 
  $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order; 
                  $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                $emailTemplate->send('emailhere','seller name', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
```

Comment: i need to add config.xml only or some other file

Comment: you need to add xml code in your marketplace module config.xml

Comment: Ok i will check

Comment: How to get Seller mail id

Comment: i think seller is login and you have his session id got it form there..

Comment: Ok thnaks i will check

Comment: Where i have to add second part code and also where i have to add seller mail id

Comment: Mentioned in code and where you are changing the status

Comment: Ok email address where to add

Comment: `email here` replace it with sellers email address

Comment: Ok can i add this into controller

Comment: Yes you can add it controller but load order after save

Comment: How to load order after save

Comment: $order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($id):