# Magento how to add custom email template

Tags: magento-1.9

```
    <?php
    Class Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer
    {
        public function deleteCustomer($observer){
            $sellerid=$observer->getCustomer()->getId();
            $sellers=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection()
                                                    ->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$sellerid));
            foreach($sellers as $seller){ $seller->delete(); }

            $sellerpro= Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$sellerid));
            foreach($sellerpro as $pro){
                $allStores = Mage::app()->getStores();
                foreach ($allStores as $_eachStoreId => $val){
                    Mage::getModel('catalog/product_status')->updateProductStatus($pro->getMageproductid(),Mage::app()->getStore($_eachStoreId)->getId(), Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
                }
                $pro->delete();
            }
        }

        public function CustomerRegister($observer){
        $data=Mage::getSingleton('core/app')->getRequest();
            if($data->getParam('wantpartner')==1){
                $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
                Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getRegisterDetail($customer);
                $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('partnerrequest');

                $emailTempVariables = array();
                $admin_storemail = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/adminemail');
                $adminEmail=$admin_storemail? $admin_storemail:Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $customer->getName();
                $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = Mage::getUrl('adminhtml/customer/edit', array('id' => $customer->getId()));

                $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                $emailTemp->setSenderName($customer->getName());
                $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($customer->getEmail());
                $emailTemp->send($adminEmail,$customer->getName(),$emailTempVariables);
            }
        }
        public function DeleteProduct($observer) { 
            $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                                                               ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid ',$observer->getProduct()->getId());
            foreach($collection as $data){          
                Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->load($data['index_id'])->delete();           
            }       
        }

        public function afterPlaceOrder($observer) { 
            $lastOrderId=$observer->getOrder()->getId();
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
            Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getProductSalesCalculation($order);

$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                        ->loadDefault('customerpartner_email');
                        $emailTemplate
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store->getId()));                                                  
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
                        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Order Updated Order #'.$order->getIncrementId()); 
      $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order; 
                      $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    $emailTemplate->send('$customer','$customer', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);

        }


        public function commissionCalculationOnComplete($observer){
            $order = $observer->getOrder();
            if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE){
                Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCommsionCalculation($order);
            }
        }

        public function afterSaveCustomer($observer){
            $customer=$observer->getCustomer();
            $customerid=$customer->getId();
            $isPartner= Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->isPartner();
            if($isPartner==1){
                $data=$observer->getRequest();
                $sid = $data->getParam('sellerassignproid');
                $unassignproid = $data->getParam('sellerunassignproid');
                $partner_type = $data->getParam('partnertype');
                if($partner_type==2)
                {
                    $collectionselectdelete = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                    $collectionselectdelete->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array($customerid));
                    foreach($collectionselectdelete as $delete){
                        $autoid=$delete->getautoid();
                    }
                    $collectiondelete = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->load($autoid);
                    $collectiondelete->delete();
                    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerid); 
                    $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('partnerdisapprove');

                    $emailTempVariables = array();      
                    $admin_storemail = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/adminemail');
                    $adminEmail=$admin_storemail? $admin_storemail:Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email'); 
                    $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $customer->getName();
                    $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();

                    $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                    $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                    $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                    $emailTemp->send($customer->getEmail(),$Username,$emailTempVariables);  
                }
                if($sid !=''||$sid!= 0){
                    Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->assignProduct($customer,$sid);
                }
                if($unassignproid !=''||$unassignproid!= 0){
                    Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->unassignProduct($customer,$unassignproid);
                }
                $wholedata=$data->getParams();
                $collectionselect = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner')->getCollection();
                $collectionselect->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$customer->getId()));
                if(count($collectionselect)==1){
                    foreach($collectionselect as $verifyrow){
                    $autoid=$verifyrow->getautoid();
                    }

                    $collectionupdate = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner')->load($autoid);
                    $collectionupdate->setcommision($wholedata['commision']);
                    $collectionupdate->save();
                    }
                else{
                    $collectioninsert=Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleperpartner');
                    $collectioninsert->setmageuserid($customer->getId());
                    $collectioninsert->setcommision($wholedata['commision']);
                    $collectioninsert->save();
                }

                /*Save seller info*/
                $collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array('eq'=>$customer->getId()));
                foreach($collection as  $value){ 
                    $data = $value; 
                    $value->settwitterid($wholedata['twitterid']);
                    $value->setfacebookid($wholedata['facebookid']);
                    $value->setprofileurl($wholedata['profileurl']);
                    $value->setcontactnumber($wholedata['contactnumber']);
                    $value->setshoptitle($wholedata['shoptitle']);
                    $value->setcomplocality($wholedata['complocality']);
                    $value->setMetaKeyword($wholedata['meta_keyword']);

                    if($wholedata['compdesi']){
                        $wholedata['compdesi'] = str_replace('script', '', $wholedata['compdesi']);
                    }
                    $value->setcompdesi($wholedata['compdesi']);

                    if($wholedata['returnpolicy']){
                        $wholedata['returnpolicy'] = str_replace('script', '', $wholedata['returnpolicy']);
                    }
                    $value->setReturnpolicy($wholedata['returnpolicy']);

                    if($wholedata['shippingpolicy']){
                        $wholedata['shippingpolicy'] = str_replace('script', '', $wholedata['shippingpolicy']);
                    }
                    $value->setShippingpolicy($wholedata['shippingpolicy']);

                    $value->setMetaDescription($wholedata['meta_description']);
                    $target =Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/avatar/';
                    if(strlen($_FILES['bannerpic']['name'])>0){
                        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["bannerpic"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        $temp = explode(".",$_FILES["bannerpic"]["name"]);
                        $img1 = $temp[0].rand(1,99999).$loid.'.'.$extension;
                        $value->setbannerpic($img1);
                        $targetb = $target.$img1; 
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['bannerpic']['tmp_name'],$targetb);
                    }
                    if(strlen($_FILES['logopic']['name'])>0){
                        $extension = pathinfo($_FILES["logopic"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        $temp1 = explode(".",$_FILES["logopic"]["name"]);
                        $img2 = $temp1[0].rand(1,99999).$loid.'.'.$extension;
                        $value->setlogopic($img2);                  
                        $targetl = $target.$img2; 
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logopic']['tmp_name'],$targetl);
                    }
                    if (array_key_exists('countrypic', $fields)) {
                        $value->setcountrypic($fields['countrypic']);
                    }
                    $value->save();
                }
            }
            else{
                    $data=$observer->getRequest();
                    $partner_type = $data->getParam('partnertype');
                    $profileurl = $data->getParam('profileurl');
                    $wholedata=$data->getParams();
                    if($partner_type==1)
                    {
                        if($profileurl!=''){
                            $profileurlcount = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                            $profileurlcount->addFieldToFilter('profileurl',$profileurl);
                            if(count($profileurlcount)==0){
                                $collectionselect = Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection();
                                $collectionselect->addFieldToFilter('mageuserid',array($customer->getId()));
                                if(count($collectionselect)>=1){
                                    foreach($collectionselect as $coll){
                                            $coll->setWantpartner('1');
                                            $coll->setpartnerstatus('Seller');
                                            $coll->setProfileurl($data->getParam('profileurl'));
                                            $coll->save();
                                    }
                                }   
                                    else{
                                        $collection=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile');
                                        $collection->setwantpartner(1);
                                        $collection->setpartnerstatus('Seller');
                                        $collection->setProfileurl($data->getParam('profileurl'));
                                        $collection->setmageuserid($customer->getId());
                                        $collection->save();
                                }
                                $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerid);

                                $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('partnerapprove');

                                $emailTempVariables = array();              
                                $admin_storemail = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/adminemail');
                                $adminEmail=$admin_storemail? $admin_storemail:Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                                $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                                $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $customer->getName();
                                $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl();

                                $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                                $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                                $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                                $emailTemp->send($customer->getEmail(),$Username,$emailTempVariables);

                            } else {
                                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('This Shop Name alreasy Exists.');
                            }   
                        }
                        else{
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Enter Shop Name of Customer.');
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

        public function checkInvoiceSubmit($observer) { 
            $seller_items_array = array();
            $invoice_seller_ids = array();
            $event = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
            foreach ($event->getAllItems() as $value) {
                $invoiceproduct = $value->getData();
                $pro_seller_id = 0;
                $product_seller = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',$invoiceproduct['product_id']);
                foreach ($product_seller as $sellervalue) {
                    if($sellervalue->getUserid()){
                        $invoice_seller_ids[$sellervalue->getUserid()] = $sellervalue->getUserid();
                        $pro_seller_id = $sellervalue->getUserid();         
                    }
                }
                if($pro_seller_id){
                    $seller_items_array[$pro_seller_id][] = $invoiceproduct;
                }
            }
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($event->getOrderId());
            foreach($invoice_seller_ids as $invoice_seller_id){
                $fetchsale = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
                $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$event->getOrderId());   
                $fetchsale->addFieldToFilter('mageproownerid',$invoice_seller_id);
                $totalprice ='';
                $totaltax_amount= 0;
                $orderinfo = '';
                    $style='style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc";';
                    $tax="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Tax</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr>";
                    $options="<tr><td ".$style."><h3>Product Options</h3></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr><tr><td ".$style."><b>Options</b></td><td ".$style."><b>Value</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";        
                foreach($fetchsale as $res){
                    $orderinfo = $orderinfo."<tr>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['mageproname']."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($res['mageproid'])->getSku()."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style." >".$res['magequantity']."</td>
                                    <td valign='top' align='left' ".$style.">".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($res['mageproprice'])."</td>
                                 </tr>";    

                    foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item){
                        if($item->getProductId()==$res['mageproid']){
                            $taxPrice = $item->getTaxAmount();
                            $totaltax_amount=$totaltax_amount + $item->getTaxAmount();
                            $taxAmount=Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($item->getTaxAmount());
                            $tax=$tax."<tr><td ".$style."><b>Tax Amount</b></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style.">".$taxAmount."</td></tr>";
                            $temp=$item->getProductOptions();

                            if (array_key_exists('options', $temp)) {
                            foreach($temp['options'] as $data){
                                $optionflag=1;
                                $options=$options."<tr><td ".$style."><b>".$data['label']."</b></td><td ".$style.">".$data['value']."</td><td ".$style."></td><td ".$style."></td></tr>";
                                }
                             }
                            else {$optionflag='';}

                         }
                    } 
                    $totalprice = $totalprice+$res['mageproprice'];
                    $userdata = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($res['mageproownerid']);              
                    $Username = $userdata['firstname'];
                    $useremail = $userdata['email'];            
                }
                $seller_info_array[$invoice_seller_id] = $userdata;

                $shipcharge = $order->getShippingAmount();
                if($totaltax_amount>0){
                    $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$tax;
                }
                if($optionflag==1){
                    $orderinfo=$orderinfo.$options;
                }
                $orderinfo = $orderinfo."</tbody><tbody><tr>
                                            <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'>Grandtotal</td>
                                            <td align='right' style='padding:3px 9px' colspan='3'><span>".Mage::app()->getStore()->formatPrice($totalprice+$totaltax_amount)."</span></td>
                                        </tr>";

                $billingId = $order->getBillingAddress()->getId();
                $billaddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($billingId);
                $billinginfo = $billaddress['firstname'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['street'].'<br/>'.$billaddress['city'].' '.$billaddress['region'].' '.$billaddress['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($billaddress['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$billaddress['telephone'];  

                if($order->getShippingAddress()!='')
                    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                else
                    $shippingId = $billingId;
                $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 

                $payment = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
                if($order->getShippingAddress()){
                    $shippingId = $order->getShippingAddress()->getId();
                    $address = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($shippingId);                
                    $shippinginfo = $address['firstname'].'<br/>'.$address['street'].'<br/>'.$address['city'].' '.$address['region'].' '.$address['postcode'].'<br/>'.Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($address['country_id'])->getName().'<br/>T:'.$address['telephone']; 
                    $shipping = $order->getShippingDescription();   
                    $shippinfo = $shippinginfo;
                    $shippingd = $shipping;     
                }

                $emailTemp = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('webkulorderinvoice');

                $emailTempVariables = array();              
                $admin_storemail = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/marketplace_options/adminemail');
                $adminEmail=$admin_storemail? $admin_storemail:Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                $adminUsername = 'Admin';
                $emailTempVariables['myvar1'] = $res['magerealorderid'];
                $emailTempVariables['myvar2'] = $res['cleared_at'];
                $emailTempVariables['myvar4'] = $billinginfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar5'] = $payment;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar6'] = $shippinfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar9'] = $shippingd;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar8'] = $orderinfo;
                $emailTempVariables['myvar3'] =$Username;

                $processedTemplate = $emailTemp->getProcessedTemplate($emailTempVariables);

                $emailTemp->setSenderName($adminUsername);
                $emailTemp->setSenderEmail($adminEmail);
                $emailTemp->send($useremail,$Username,$emailTempVariables);
            }
            Mage::dispatchEvent('mp_product_sold',array('itemwithseller'=>$seller_items_array));
        }       
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Here you can create email template app/locale/en_US/template/email/ where in *en_US* is your locale

Comment: ya i already created

Comment: follow this link for custom emails - www.inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails

Comment: you need to add this code in your config.xml under <config><global><template><email> tag

Comment: yes i followed same tag

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95797/magento-send-order-update-mails  check this

Comment: `follow this link for custom emails - www.inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails ` by atu;

Comment: @QaisarSatti where i want to add second part of code

Comment: where you want to send the email..

Comment: > I suggest following link will help you to understand http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/ **I hope this will help you.**

Comment: i am using Marketplace they configure only config.xml not mention any where

Comment: you want to send the email on some action put the sending code there.

Comment: ya that's what i told i can't find that code in that

Comment: which action you want to send email?

Comment: While customer place order that time i wan to to send mail to that seller

Comment: `sale order save after` check this event

Comment: In Which file??

Comment: is it in controller file?

Comment: @QaisarSatti i updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple send email in observer..

```
public function afterPlaceOrder($observer) {
           $store = Mage::app()
            ->getWebsite()
            ->getDefaultGroup()
            ->getDefaultStoreId(); 
            $lastOrderId=$observer->getOrder()->getId();
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
     $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$lastOrderId); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
         $id=$res['mageproownerid'];
         $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

   }

 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                        ->loadDefault('customerpartner_email');
                        $emailTemplate
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store));                                                  
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
                        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Order Updated Order #'.$order->getIncrementId()); 
      $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order; 
                      $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    $emailTemplate->send($customerData->getEmail(),$customerData->getFirstName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);

     }
```

Comment: Where and how to load email and seller email

Comment: `$emailTemplate->send('emailhere','seller name', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);` in last line add it. i thin order id is related to seller id search for it and get data as he is using in seller dashboard to dispaly

Comment: After adding this code i can't able to place order

Comment: check for error log what error in that?

Comment: Sysytem log only is there 2016-01-06T07:24:02+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: cookieParams  in /var/www/html/domain/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 100

Comment: did you check the console for error

Comment: var/log only system log there is no file

Comment: i added code in observer.php after that i placed order it not working then i check log file in var/log

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console

Comment: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://videomergerapp.com/checkout/onepage/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://videomergerapp.com/mpcashondelivery/captcha/index/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: can you attached the screenshot?

Comment: i updated question

Comment: these are loading try to click on save order then check the console

Comment: seriousley i can't get can you please check this http://videomergerapp.com/say-cheese-brown-xiaomi-redmi-1s-phone-case.html

Comment: shipping error i got..

Comment: that means what i ll do

Comment: can you paste full observer code?

Comment: i updated question

Comment: i did not see my code there??

Comment: i removed because can't able to place order so that

Comment: `$customer` where you get this? it is empty not defined in function

Comment: Even i tried this also but it's not working $customer = $observer->getCustomer();

Comment: this is order observer get user from observer but you want the seller email and name.

Comment: Yes how to get that

Comment: last answer where you sku you load the data of order that contain the seller id just check it you will get data from there.

Comment: last answer in the sense ?

Comment: updated the answer in that loop you will get the seller id just load the customer and get the seller email

Comment: How to load that

Comment: updated with your all requirement check it..

Comment: Still now same i can't able to place order

Comment: now you have to find error from console..

Comment: it showing Mixed Content error only

Comment: that are loading error try to move to checkout step you can see the progress in console. check them

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in <b>/var/www/html/videomergerapp
/app/code/local/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Observer.php</b> on line <b>65</b><br />

Comment: Line 65 code $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store->getId()));

Comment: updated answer kindly check....

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getEmail() on a non-object in <b>/var/www/html/videomergerapp
/app/code/local/Webkul/Marketplace/Model/Observer.php</b> on line <b>75</b><br />

Comment: $emailTemplate->send($customerData->getEmail(),$customerData->getFirstName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);

Comment: try this code in phtml file and test it and check what is missing.. this is complete code what you need just pass the seller id

Comment: In whick phtml file

Comment: any phtml file because in observer you have place order again and again try code when it error free and working then move to observer

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object in /var/www/html/domain/app/design/frontend/default/em0113/template/checkout/onepage.phtml on line 68

Comment: add static id of order just for testing bro

Comment: ya i added still same error Call to a member function getEmail()

Comment: print_r($res); check what you are getting

Comment: I placed after for loop but nothing printed

Comment: check collection return something what order id you passed it?

Comment: $lastOrderId=100001920;

Comment: place the real order id...

Comment: it's real order id only

Comment: this is increment id the real order id will be 51 or 200 etc

Comment: i can't understand can you please updadte answer

Comment: try `1796`  as a order id..

Comment: i commant this  //$emailTemplate->send($customerData->getEmail(),$customerData->getFirstName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null); may be prob;em is this only

Comment: the how will email will be send you have to pass the email to send the email to seller

Comment: <?php  $store = Mage::app() ->getWebsite()
            ->getDefaultGroup()
            ->getDefaultStoreId(); 
            $lastOrderId=1796;
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
     $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$lastOrderId); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
         $id=$res['mageproownerid'];
         $customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

   }
   print_r($res);

Comment: it it right????

Comment: print inside the foreach loop

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: print_r($customerData);

Comment: Check my updated question

Comment: move this code outside the foreach `$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);` and open the send email code and check

Comment: Check my updated question. I got a mail but order id miss match some content also miss

Comment: paste your email template with this code in new question i think this question also messed up......

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/97011/send-mail-after-place-order

Answer (score 0):

This may not be monitored anymore, but it's worth a shot.

Does SetSenderEmail work for sending through a shared mailbox?  I seem to have problems doing it and suspect that it is because it is a shared email account.

Using Exchange.