# Send mail after place order

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to send mail to seller after place order to seller product

```
<customerpartner_email_template>
                    <label>Admin mail to check that some product is sold</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/customer_partner.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </customerpartner_email_template>
```

**observer.php**

```
<?php 

 $store = Mage::app()
            ->getWebsite()
            ->getDefaultGroup()
            ->getDefaultStoreId(); 
            $lastOrderId=1796;
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
     $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$lastOrderId); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
         $id=$res['mageproownerid'];

/*print_r($res);*/
//print_r($customerData);
   }
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);


 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                        ->loadDefault('customerpartner_email_template');
                        $emailTemplate
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store));                                                  
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
                        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Order Updated Order #'.$order->getIncrementId()); 
      $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order; 
                      $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    $emailTemplate->send($customerData->getEmail(),$customerData->getFirstName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);


                    ?>
```

But i got this only, Even i got mis match order id also

[image]

mail template

```
<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;">Dear {{var myvar2}},</h1>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;">I would like to inform you that your product is been sold from our store.</p>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;">Order ID: {{var myvar1}}.</p>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;">Quantity Ordered: {{var myvar3}}.</p>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 8px 0;">Total Cost: {{var myvar4}}.</p>
                            <p style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0; font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0; 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you </p></center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

**config.xml**

```
<events>
            <catalog_product_delete_after>
                <observers>
                   <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>DeleteProduct</method>
                   </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
            </catalog_product_delete_after>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                   <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>CustomerRegister</method>
                   </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
            <customer_delete_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                        <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>deleteCustomer</method>
                    </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_delete_commit_after>
            <sales_order_place_after>
              <observers>
               <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                 <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                  <method>afterPlaceOrder</method>
               </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
              </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>

            <sales_order_invoice_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                        <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>checkInvoiceSubmit</method>
                    </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_save_after>
            <adminhtml_customer_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>afterSaveCustomer</method>
                    </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
               </observers>
            </adminhtml_customer_save_after>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                        <class>Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>commissionCalculationOnComplete</method>
                    </Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
<template>
            <email>
                <adminnotifymoney>
                    <label>Admin Notify For Credit</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/notifyadminformoney.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </adminnotifymoney>
                <partnerrequest>
                    <label>Partner Request</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/partnerrequest.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </partnerrequest>
                <partnerapprove>
                    <label>Partner Approved</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/partnerapprove.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </partnerapprove>
                <partnerdisapprove>
                    <label>Partner Disapprove</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/partnerdisapprove.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </partnerdisapprove>
                <partnerdeny>
                    <label>Partner Deny</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/denypartnermail.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </partnerdeny>
                <productdeny>
                    <label>Product Deny</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/productdenymail.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </productdeny>
                <partnercreditinfo>
                    <label>partner Notify for Credit</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/partnercreditinfo.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </partnercreditinfo>
                <approveproduct>
                    <label>Approve My Product</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/admininformnewpro.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </approveproduct>
                <customerpartner_email_template>
                    <label>Admin mail to check that some product is sold</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/customer_partner.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </customerpartner_email_template>
                <customerpartner_email>
                    <label>Notify Partner when its product sold</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/notifycheckoutpartner.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </customerpartner_email>
                <requesttobecomepartner_email>
                    <label>Notify Admin to make me partner</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/webkulcustomerpartnewreqest.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </requesttobecomepartner_email>
                <querypartner_email>
                    <label>Ask question from partner for its particular product</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/webkulquerypartneremail.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </querypartner_email>
                <askquerypartner_email>
                    <label>Ask question from partner</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/askquerypartneremail.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </askquerypartner_email>                
                <queryadminemail>
                    <label>Ask question from admin by seller</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/webkulqueryadminemail.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </queryadminemail>
                <whenproductapproved>
                    <label>When the product is Approved mail send to partner</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/admininapprovedit.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </whenproductapproved>
                <orderinvoice>
                    <label>When invoice is created for an order</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/partener_order_invoice.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </orderinvoice> 
                <webkulorderinvoice>
                    <label>When invoice is created for an order</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/webkul_order_invoice.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </webkulorderinvoice>
                <sellertransactionmail>
                    <label>When transaction is created by for seller's order</label>
                    <file>marketplacepartner/sellertransactionmail.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </sellertransactionmail>
            </email>            
        </template>

<rewrite>
                    <customer_edit_tabs>Webkul_Marketplace_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
```

**commissionCalculationOnComplete**

```
public function commissionCalculationOnComplete($observer){
        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE){
            Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCommsionCalculation($order);
        }

        $store = Mage::app()
            ->getWebsite()
            ->getDefaultGroup()
            ->getDefaultStoreId(); 
            $lastOrderId=1796;
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
     $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$lastOrderId); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
         $id=$res['mageproownerid'];

/*print_r($res);*/
//print_r($customerData);
   }
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);


 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                        ->loadDefault('customerpartner_email_template');
                        $emailTemplate
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store));                                                  
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
                        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Order Updated Order #'.$order->getIncrementId()); 
     $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] =$customerData->getFirstName();
           $emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] =$order->getData('total_qty_ordered');
     $emailTemplateVariables['myvar4'] =$order->getGrandTotal();
      $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order; 
                      $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    $emailTemplate->send($customerData->getEmail(),$customerData->getFirstName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
    }
    }
```

Comment: marketplacepartner/customer_partner.html paste that template too

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added your require vairable check it

```
 $store = Mage::app()
            ->getWebsite()
            ->getDefaultGroup()
            ->getDefaultStoreId(); 
            $lastOrderId= $observer->getOrder()->getId(); //order id pass here
            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($lastOrderId);
     $_collection = Mage::getModel('marketplace/saleslist')->getCollection();
    $_collection->addFieldToFilter('mageorderid',$lastOrderId); 

    foreach($_collection as $res){
         $id=$res['mageproownerid'];

/*print_r($res);*/
//print_r($customerData);
   }
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);


 $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                                        ->loadDefault('customerpartner_email_template');
                        $emailTemplate
                        ->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store));                                                  
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name'));
                        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email')); 
                        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Order Updated Order #'.$order->getIncrementId()); 
     $emailTemplateVariables['myvar1'] = $order->getIncrementId();
                    $emailTemplateVariables['myvar2'] =$customerData->getFirstName();
           $emailTemplateVariables['myvar3'] =$order->getData('total_qty_ordered');
     $emailTemplateVariables['myvar4'] =$order->getGrandTotal();
      $emailTemplateVariables['order'] = $order; 
                      $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
                    $emailTemplate->send($customerData->getEmail(),$customerData->getFirstName(), $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
```

Comment: last order id can i keep it 1796 it self

Comment: How to get in this Order ID: .

Quantity Ordered: .

Total Cost: .

Comment: i think in observer you added the code.. for getting the order id

Comment: If i add this code i din't got any mail if its 1796 i got a mail what ill do but order id is mismatch

Comment: updated the code check it....

Comment: I didn't got seller mail

Comment: After this got in mail sku also not showing

Comment: where is sku in this email? i don't see any?

Comment: ya in order conformation mail sku not showing also if use this $observer->getOrder()->getId(); seller did n't got any mail

Comment: then you have find where the marketplace insert his order place email there i think seller not save records yet

Comment: <orderinvoice>
     <label>When invoice is created for an order</label>
     <file>marketplacepartner/partener_order_invoice.html</file>
     <type>html</type>
    </orderinvoice>

Comment: is it related to that

Comment: can you paste config.xml so i can check it

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: add the `event` and `rewrite` config.xml

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: `commissionCalculationOnComplete` add in this you will see the seller id there and all data your required check it place email send code there

Comment: check my updated question place order not working

Comment: i think after the order is complete then it is added to seller account. can you check am i correct?

Comment: Ya but mail it's not displaying

Comment: then you have to send email on order complete am i right?

Comment: ya but that's doesn't contain sku only ststus completed that's all

Comment: what you want to send in that email?

Comment: Your order has been completed that's all(you are asking for order complete mail right)

Comment: no when order assingn to seller then

Comment: Assign seller sku only it's showing in mail

Comment: Now what i will do where i want to add this code

Comment: i think on order complete you will sent the email.

Comment: Ok sku not a problem i can manage but i want to send mail to seller

Comment: this is the code place it anywhere it will send email just pass the `orderid`

Comment: can you please update that code

Comment: it is update now it up to you how to pass the order id. that all from today myside.....

Comment: can you please tell me How to pass and where to pass

Comment: `$lastOrderId=$observer->getOrder()->getId();` in this you pass order id rest will be same

Comment: it it correct Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);

Comment: use this `$lastOrderId` it used three other places too

Comment: i can't get can you please give me that code

Comment: $lastOrderId= $observer->getOrder()->getId($lastOrderId);

Comment: $lastOrderId= $lastOrderId;  use it like that..

Comment: Ya thanks can you please tell me how to get varible